# All parameters in Web Service contract operations cannot be a null

Tags: wcf, f#

When I am adding one method to my Web Service I get the error when open the WSDL in the browser:

> All parameters in Web Service contract operations cannot be a null

Here is method declaration:

```
[<System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvokeAttribute>]
abstract PostFile: System.IO.Stream -> bool
```

And here is a current method implementation:

```
member x.PostFile(stream : Stream) : bool =
        let filepath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "uploadedfile.jpg")                

        try
            let outstream : FileStream = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
            let bufferLen : int = 4096
            let buffer : byte array = Array.zeroCreate bufferLen
            let count : int = 0

            let mutable count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)
            if count > 0 then
                outstream.Write(buffer, 0, count)

            while (count > 0) do
                count <- stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)
                outstream.Write(buffer, 0, count)

            outstream.Close()
            stream.Close()
            true
        with
            | exn ->
                printfn "Exception: \n%s" exn.Message
                reraise()
```

Here is a [full stack from the browser](http://pastebin.com/LREHZX0V) (sorry, for russian).

If I comment this one (and only one method) all works fine.  What is the reason of the error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I have found the error.  It is necessary to set variable name in the contract:

```
abstract PostFile: stream:System.IO.Stream -> bool
```